# 05 VW Passat Turns over, won’t start

Tags: vw, fuel-system, fuel-injectors, power-loss

this car has been a problem from the beginning... engine light on, codes say misfire. Started overheating so I replaced thermostat. Still had hardly any power or acceleration, engine light flashes a few times every time I start car, now all of the sudden it won’t start. It’s not the battery because I tried to jump it, all the lights come on fine and everything it just won’t start. Could it be fuel injectors? And if so how would I know if they need replaced or Just cleaned?

Comment: Check everything logically. Do you have a spark? Is there fuel? Is the air filter good`? etc "Beginning" & "misfire" - did you solve the misfire or just leave it? how long has it been there?

Comment: This car was given to me about a month ago, has had a misfire the whole time I’ve had it, changed coils and spark plugs, misfire was still happening. It started to overheat so I changed the thermostat, that worked for a little bit than it kept overheating, coolant problems i guess, than it ran alright for about 3 days and all the sudden it would take a few seconds longer to start, then the same day it wouldn’t start at all. All the lights come on like normal and everything, tried to jump it too, didn’t work. I don’t have a way of testing much from home unfortunately.

Comment: And I don’t have the money to have another mechanic look at it, was hoping someone with similar issues might have some guidance, can’t figure out if it’s the alternator or fuel injectors or what is it

Comment: Also to add, I do have a cracked head gasket, but about 2 weeks ago I put K-seal in there to hopefully help but I think since it was overheating that it wasn’t getting coolant right so the sealant didn’t work. Could the cracked head gasket be the problem with not starting? It doesn’t see like that has affected the car toooo much, seems to be little problems that I fix and a week later another little problem pops up. Could that be because of small cracked head gasket

Comment: 4 cyl or v6?  You say cracked head gasket? You mean a blown head gasket or cracked head?  Either one could keep the car from starting if bad enough to let coolant into the cylinders.

Comment: 4 cyl. Had misfires in cyl 2 &3 already, and what’s the difference between blown or cracked head gasket?

Comment: A friend came over and tested some stuff, thinks the fuel pump is out, does what I’ve described so far sound like fuel pump problems?

Comment: When I turn the key to accessory mode you don’t hear the fuel pump come on like normal for a second so it does make sense that it’s not working but would that make the car be able to start again if I replaced it